# i converted a bitmap picture to byte arraye and string .how can i convert this string to that bitmap picture again?

Tags: c#

```
 public byte[] PictureByteArray
        {
            get
            {
                //get a TypeConverter object for converting Bitmap to bytes
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
                byte[] byteArr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(source, typeof(byte[]));
                return byteArr;
            }
            set
            {
                source = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(value));
            }
        }


  System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            s = enc.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a property here since you want the property to accept at byte array and return an bitmap. A property must get and set the same data type. You have to make two methods for this. One for image->byte array and one for byte array->image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use these two methods for converting an image to a byte array, and back again, for example when transferring an image to a web service, and retrieving it back again:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn) {
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imageIn);
  image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  return ms.ToArray();
}

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray) {
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
  Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
  return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: BTW, I think you're leaking a bitmap in ImageToByteArray.  You should dispose the temporary bitmap after saving it.